# Cooja - In-Building Models & Mote Choice

Tags: contiki, texas-instruments, cooja

I'm currently working on a 3-months projects based on Contiki-NG and Cooja at the university and I have to create In-Building models and I would like to ask two questions please :

1) Is it possible to add an obstacle in Cooja like a wall or something else or do you know any similar tool able to do that ?

2) In Cooja, what is the closest mote I can use to simulate a Texas Instrument CC2650 LaunchPad ? (z1 mote isn't available in the new version of Contiki-NG)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you can have obstacles in Cooja. For that you need to use the MRM radio medium (*Multi-path Ray-tracing radio medium*). There is not a lot of documentation, but read the [documenting comments in the source code](http://%20https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/tools/cooja/apps/mrm/java/org/contikios/mrm/MRM.java) and try it out.

2) It is not possible to simulate the hardware-level details of CC2650. Try using Cooja motes: their support is much improved in Contiki-NG. Also, we are going to add another msp430-based mote with more RAM in the next release of Contiki-NG (v4.2).

Comment: I would like to use that MRM radio medium but do you know how we import it on Cooja please ? It is not available in the drop down menu of Mote. Concerning the link, it wasn't working but I found out the file: [https://github.com/contiki-ng/cooja/blob/22b1262d9e668d9cf6c8eaf70715f1bcd5728642/apps/mrm/java/org/contikios/mrm/MRM.java]

Comment: You probably need to add it to cooja extensions. I think this shows how to add an extension https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1RTfcUMUmo

Comment: I've tried that too but the mrm option doesn't appears in the Tools drop down menu. I'm not sure if I need to rebuild the plugin since everything is correctly configured even in the `DEFAULT_PROJECTDIRS` under the External tools paths menu.